# Remove gap in Highcharts column chart from null value from JSON file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I'd like to justify columns by category on a Highcharts column chart, so it corrects null values. The function below was written by Grzegorz does just that. But when I try to add the function in the React official wrapper, it returns "element" undefined. How do I adapt this to the React official wrapper. Remember I only want to ignore the gaps from null values, not zeros. Here is a codesandbox of my code, the logic should be in the Chart.js component.
[Chart is in ./components/Chart.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/luciomcamargo/graph)

```
var justifyColumns = function (chart) {
    var categoriesWidth = chart.plotSizeX / (1 + chart.xAxis[0].max - chart.xAxis[0].min),
        distanceBetweenColumns = 0,
        each = Highcharts.each,
        sum, categories = chart.xAxis[0].categories,
        number;
    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        each(chart.series, function (p, k) {
            if (p.visible) {
                each(p.data, function (ob, j) {
                    if (ob.category == categories[i]) {
                        sum++;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        distanceBetweenColumns = categoriesWidth / (sum + 1);
        number = 1;
        each(chart.series, function (p, k) {
            if (p.visible) {
                each(p.data, function (ob, j) {
                    if (ob.category == categories[i]) {
                        ob.graphic.element.x.baseVal.value = i * categoriesWidth + distanceBetweenColumns * number - ob.pointWidth / 2;
                        number++;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you provided does not work with `null` values, which you can also notice without the react wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2q18zkcj/

You need to change the way the function works:

```
function justifyColumns(chart) {
  var categoriesWidth = chart.plotSizeX / (1 + chart.xAxis[0].max - chart.xAxis[0].min),
    distanceBetweenColumns = 0,
    each = Highcharts.each,
    sum, categories = chart.xAxis[0].categories,
    number;
  for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    sum = 0;
    each(chart.series, function (p, k) {
      if (p.visible) {
        each(p.data, function (ob, j) {
          if (ob.category == categories[i] && ob.y !== null) {
            sum++;
          }
        });
      }
    });
    distanceBetweenColumns = categoriesWidth / (sum + 1);
    number = 1;
    each(chart.series, function (p, k) {
      if (p.visible) {
        each(p.data, function (ob, j) {
          if (ob.category == categories[i] && ob.y !== null) {
            ob.graphic.element.x.baseVal.value = i * categoriesWidth + distanceBetweenColumns * number - ob.pointWidth / 2;
            number++;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/p5j09zrz8q

Comment: Thanks Pawel.  But I was hoping with this function to eliminate the gap caused by the null values and join the last category columns together.  I can toy around with pointPadding and groupPadding, but then the other category  columns end up overlapping, which isnt the effect I desire.

Comment: All I want is to eliminate the gap caused by the null values,  so the chart displays as if they were not there.

Comment: Hi Lucio Camargo, The gap is eliminated by the function, columns the are proportionally placed on the category. Do you want to have the same distance between every column on every category?

Comment: groupPadding and pointPadding zero.  The problem now is when I do that the first 2 columns are overlapping. I want evenly spaced conjoined categories. I just want the gap between the last category column to disappear. The gap is caused by a null value.

Comment: https://res.cloudinary.com/dijtl91qi/image/upload/v1544463410/gap_x4oajq.png here is a screenshot of what Id like to achieve

Comment: Hi Lucio Camargo, Please check now this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/p5j09zrz8q, your problem should be fixed. Also this jsfiddle could be useful: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n3v4bst8/